# ¿Por qué "fue" y no "era"?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito

Hace uno o dos años que estudio el español, pero aún tengo dificultades con los pretéritos indefinido e imperfecto. Mi lengua nativa es el inglés, así que definitivamente tiene algo que ver con eso. Hoy hice unos ejercicios que encontré en la página web de alguna escuela e intenté hacerlos. He aquí tres fragmentos de los ejercicios (las palabras en negrita son las que tuve que escribir):

> El chico **era** bibliotecario y **trabajaba** en la universidad. En
>   la biblioteca de la universidad, **hablaron** por primera vez. Pero el
>   encuentro en la biblioteca no ***era*** casual...
>
> El encuentro en el bar no ***era*** una coincidencia. La chica
>   **esperaba** allí al chico mientras **leía** mensajes en los sobres de azúcar.
>
> Pero, por la noche, cuando el chico **cruzaba** una calle, la chica lo
>   **atropelló** con su bicicleta. ¡Eso sí ***era*** una casualidad!

Ya que explican a menudo en toda parte que el pretérito imperfecto se usa para descripciones, ¿por qué no son correctos los "era" en cursiva? No narra ningún evento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **fue** es el pretérito perfecto simple (o pretérito indefinido).
- **era** es el pretérito imperfecto.

La diferencia entre pretérito perfecto simple y pretérito imperfecto es complicada. Sin embargo, puede resumirse en:

- El pretérito **perfecto** simple se usa cuando nos referimos a una **acción puntual** en el pasado.
- El pretérito **imperfecto** se usa cuando nos referimos a una **acción habitual**.

Analicemos el primer caso:

> El chico **era** bibliotecario y **trabajaba** en la universidad. En
>   la biblioteca de la universidad, **hablaron** por primera vez. Pero el
>   encuentro en la biblioteca no ***era*** casual...

- El chico trabajaba como bibliotecario -> algo habitual -> pretérito imperfecto -> *era*.
- Un día determinado el chico y alguien más tuvieron una conversación -> algo puntual -> pretérito perfecto simple -> *hablaron* y *fue*.

---

He aquí alguna lectura interesante para ver más ejemplos al respecto:

- [El pretérito y el imperfecto en la enseñanza del español como segunda lengua](http://www.cuadernoscervantes.com/ele_52_preterito.html)
- [Gramática - El pretérito simple y el pretérito imperfecto](http://www.multikultura.org.uk/spanish/grammar/gram_index.php?c=3)

Comment: Recientemente pedí a un hispanohablante que me explicase las diferencias entre estos dos pretéritos, pero en otro contexto. Me explicó que el indefinido "suena como el resumen de una historia de la que probablemente no vayamos a hablar más," mientras que el imperfecto "te invita a imaginarte una escena en la que hay una reconstrucción mental de la situación y que probablemente vaya a hablarte de lo que ocurre en este espacio mental." Entonces, ¿por qué no aplica al segundo caso arriba? "El encuentro en el bar no era una coincidencia" indica que va a empezar a contar lo que pasaba, ¿no?

Comment: Además, ¡me fue extremadamente útil el primer enlace! Muchas gracias por habérmelo dado.

Comment: @x1704e cuando decimos "El encuentro en el bar no era una coincidencia" suena, ciertamente, como algo narrativo e inicio de una historia. Sin embargo, al referirse a un hecho puntual (un encuentro fortuito, tal vez), la versión con "fue" es la usada si no queremos darle el toque novelesco sino más bien descriptivo. Pero sí, la explicación que te dieron también puede ser útil para entender la diferencia y si lees historias noveladas encontrarás muchos pretéritos indefinidos.

Comment: @x1704e por cierto, si la respuesta te ha sido útil puedes marcarla como tal apretando en el símbolo ☑ que está debajo del contador de votos. Puedes ver más información al respecto en [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)